# using (Matlab) dll name at top of classes C#

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, using

I created a C# program in Visual studio 2017 (Framework 4.5.2) which calls 2 different Matlab dll's that I created myself (makesquareproject.dll and calibrationsgproject.dll). Both dll's are made using the Matlab Library Compiler (.NET Assembly). I added the dll's in the References of the project and they are called with the following code throughout the program:

```
double[] points = new double[] { 4, 2, 3 }; // example
MWNumericArray mwpoints= new MWNumericArray(points);

MWArray[] result = MatlabHelper.Ml.MakeSquare(1, mwpoints); // MakeSquare is a function of the MakeSquareClass --> makesquareproject-dll          
MWArray[] result2 = MatlabHelper.Lib.CalibrationSG(2, mwpoints); // CalibrationSG is a function of the CalibrationSGClass--> calibrationsgproject-dll
```

The MatlabHelper class looks like this:

```
using makesquareproject; // dll that contains MakeSquare function

namespace myProject
{
    class MatlabHelper
    {
        private static CalibrationSGClass _lib;
        private static MakeSquareClass _ms

        public static CalibrationSGClass Lib
        {
            get
            {
                if (_lib == null)
                    _lib = new CalibrationSGClass (); // CalibrationSGClass is the class name that is chosen when the calibrationsgproject-dll is created using the Library Compiler in Matlab
                return _lib;
            }
        }    

        public static MakeSquareClass Ms
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ms == null)
                    _ms = new MakeSquareClass (); // MakeSquareClass is the class name that is chosen when the makesquareproject-dll is created using the Library Compiler in Matlab
                return _ms;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I noticed that for the makesquareproject-dll I have to add `using makesquareproject;` at the top of the `MatlabHelper` and nothing at the top of the classes that use `MatlabHelper`. Opposite to that, I don't have to put `using calibrationsgproject;` to the top of `MatlabHelper` but I have to add it to all classes that use `MatlabHelper`. Why is this the case and do I do something wrong?

Comment: What are the class/methods in calibrationsgproject?

Comment: I'll edit my post to make that more clear.

Comment: You have Ms in your MatlabHelper and Ml in your first code excerpt, is this the exact code?

Comment: I changed the name to make it clear for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `using` is only a shortcut to use a type without prefixing it by the namespace (you could write `makesquareproject.MakeSquareClass` and remove the using).

Do not mix `using` (which is only a help to write your code) and the reference to the dll, necessary to find any objects from this dll (all project which use MatlabHelper have to reference makesquareproject - if you go in your bin folder, you will find the dll and it is loaded at runtime)

So, MakeSquareClass is not written in any other function -> you don't need `using makesquareproject` in other file (it doesn't mean the type won't be used, the type is resolved correctly as makesquareproject.MakeSquareClass).

I'm not sure on the behaviour you describe though - are you sure `CalibrationSGClass`  is defined in `calibrationsgproject`? Check the namespace of it (via go to reference if you are on visual studio for example, or `GetType()` and retrieve namespace), I assume it's defined in makesquareproject also.

From what you post, I would say MakeSquareClass  and CalibrationSGClass are defined in makesquareproject, and MWArray or other is defined in calibrationsgproject. To be sure, remove using and check the exception, you wil known which types are unknown

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. When I remove the `using makesquareproject`, MakeSquareClass is underlined in red. Only MakeSquareClass is defined in `makesquareproject`. Why would `CalibrationSGClass` not be defined in `calibrationsgproject`? I made both dll's myself so I'm sure what is inside. `MWArray` is a .dll provided by Matlab so it's definitely not defined in `calibrationsgproject`.

Comment: in the class you provided, if CalibrationSGClass  was defined in calibrationsgproject and you don't have using, this could not compile. Can you check the namespace of CalibrationSGClass?

Comment: Via References: public class CalibrationSGClass Member of calibrationsgproject

Comment: The class CalibrationSGClass was also defined in another dll that I used some weeks ago which somehow still seems to be linked to my project. Probably that's why it's secretly using it and why it's not actually referring to calibrationsgproject. Therefore, `using calibrationsgproject` is not necessary in `MatlabHelper`.

Comment: pay attention in this case - this may not be the class you want. So I assume you had an additional using to some namespace in your file - remove it and replace it by the calibrationsgproject

Comment: Yes, of course, I removed it and linked everything properly.